# yammer client application external networks 401

Tags: yammer

I am creating a windows plugin which would access Yammer data like groups user follows etc, for this i created a client application and accessed yammer rest api using client id and access token i get after user allows my app to access his data in a consent page. I am able to successfully do all this when people of my network are trying to login but this does not work when the plugin is being used by people of other networks, I am able to receive the access token after the user gives his consent in user consent page, but when i try to access his data like fetching groups using rest uRL i get an error saying "{"response":{"stat":"fail","code":17,"message":"Attempt to access a protected resource failed."}}"
please be noted the client app i created is not yet deployed into Global App directory, I really doubt if this is the actual cause of the issue, because i think if this was an issue it should not have recognized the client id itself and would not have shown the external network users the consent page too. may be if i am wrong please correct me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access users on other networks' data, your app must be globalized (even if you don't want it to be listed in the Global App Directory). Without the user's consent, your app is not allowed to attempt to login on behalf of the user, thus they see the popup for authentication, and then the auth process fails because the app is not globalized.

Comment: oh ok... Thank you..got it... Also can i know what is the process to publish an app to global directory, I have sent a request for approval 4 days back but still it shows me as Pending Approval.