# yam.platform.request always fails with "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Tags: yammer

I try to use the yammer api. I did everything like specified in the docs (https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/js-sdk):

- I created my own Yammer app, with my website (https) domain set in the Javascript Origins
- I use the login button to receive my Auth token.

I set the token with yam.platform.setAuthToken

But any following request with yam.platform.request fails with "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" although I can see in the network console that the correct token is sent through the Authorisation Bearer Header.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that my code was working when accessing my home-network. For accessing any other network that i am a member of, the Yammer app should be globalized, see [yammer client application external networks 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301887/yammer-client-application-external-networks-401)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to set `yam.platform.setAuthToken` yourself - that is taken care of by `yam.platform.getLoginStatus`.

You can receive the token from the response object provided to the callback function passed to getLoginStatus if you need to, but if your JS queries the API from the browser itself, there is no need for that.